# Making native library for CN1 framework maven

Tags: maven, codenameone

I wanted to contribute in java so i found a problem https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3665 here i have to make a cn1 library for app review using maven. i asked the author he gave me a reference to another cn1 library made previously but i am still confused where to start and HOW!
https://github.com/codenameone/cn1-codescan here is the reference

I actually dont know which platform to use, I have knowledge about android studio intermediate level

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where you're stuck. I commented on the issue about the latest problem.